# On Os X, what others possible methods besides modifying the hosts file are there to re-route all http request to a local html file?

Tags: macos

Modifying the hosts file requires a mac app to ask for the user's admin password every time which does not offer a good UX. Are there any other way to block internet (or just websites) access for a limited time on Mac Os X?

Comment: When you think about it, how could there be?  Anything as serious as modifying where web requests get routed to will require administrator permissions.  If it didn't, what would stop malware from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a helper tool for your app, which could receive *permanent* permissions and place it into /usr/local/bin/

Then you would only have to ask for the user's admin password once, to install the helper tool and set the persmissions.

```
chown -R 0:0 [HELPER_TOOL]
chmod -R 4755 [HELPER_TOOL]
```

Comment: Note that the helper tool has to be a binary, not a script.  There are security problems with setuid scripts, so OS X disables them.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ipfw` instead of messing with name resolution.